# Replacing section sign `"§"`

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to replace Minecraft Color Code (§0-9A-FK-OR) into `""` like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4quf.png).

So I tried with this source (also tried without escaping `"§"`):

```
"§a╔══════ §8§o[§9§oUS§8§o] §e§Server §6§lName §a══════╗"
.gsub('/\xA7[0-9A-FK-OR]+/i', '')
```

[irb console screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCflc.png)

However it was not replaced. What is my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing your Rubular screenshot, this is what you should be doing:

```
str = "§a╔══════ §8§o[§9§oUS§8§o] §e§Server §6§lName §a══════╗"
str.gsub(/§[0-9A-FK-OR]+/i,"")
# => "╔══════ [US] §Server  ══════╗"
```

**Your Mistake:**

You are placing regex pattern inside `''` in your `gsub` command. If you put a pattern inside `''` it will be treated as a String not a pattern. And hence your regex wont work as expected.

Comment: I had got multicast error when without '. but now it is helpful for me. Thank you!!!

Comment: If you put a pattern inside `''` it will be treated as a string not a pattern. So your regex wont work as expected.